# Web scraping - try one URL and if it fails, try different URL

Tags: r, web-scraping, while-loop

I'm creating a script that will automatically scrape monthly data from a website. It downloads a zip file and unpacks it. Sometimes the website doesn't update their data on time, so I need to set a condition where it tries the URL associated with the most recent month (ex - m202002.zip) and if it fails, then it grabs the previous month's data (ex - m202001.zip).

Here's the basic download script:

```
if (!require('lubridate')) install.packages('lubridate', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', dependencies=TRUE); library('lubridate')
if (!require('download')) install.packages('download', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org', dependencies=TRUE); library('download')

# Set dates
today <- Sys.Date() # today
current_year <- format(as.Date(Sys.Date()), '%Y') # current year
previous_1month <- format(as.Date(today %m+% months(-1)), '%m') # last month
previous_2month <- format(as.Date(today %m+% months(-2)), '%m') # month before last

# Set directory
data_dir <- 'G:/path/to/file/'
website_dir <- 'https://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/uswem/web/conus/eta/modis_eta/monthly/downloads/m'

# Download and unpack most recent file
download.file(paste0(website_dir, current_year, previous_1month, '.zip'), destfile=paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), mode='wb')
unzip(paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), exdir=data_dir)
```

I'm thinking I need a while() loop, which I'm not super familiar with. Here's my approach, but the code doesn't work. It appears only be downloading the second file regardless of circumstance (e.g., if I provide an initial URL that is available, it doesn't download it, only the second one).

```
while(TRUE)
{
  zip <- download.file(paste0(website_dir, current_year, previous_1month, '.zip'), destfile=paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), mode='wb')
  if(!is(zip, 'try-error')) break
    {
    next
}
    else
    {
      zip <- download.file(paste0(website_dir, current_year, previous_2month, '.zip'), destfile=paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), mode='wb')  
    }
  }
unzip(paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), exdir=data_dir)
```

Comment: (Bravo, the first "correct" use of `require` (as opposed to `library`) I've seen in a question on SO.) *"but the code doesn't work"*, can you explain that? It helps to know how something fails, including all warning/error messages associated with it, or how the result is different than expected.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you, I've edited to be more explicit. My code doesn't run - just produces a "while(TRUE) +" in the console.

Comment: `while(TRUE)` will just generate an infinite loop. You need to `break` out of it somehow. Also, think about how you can do a minimal reproducible example, you'll probably figure it out by making the example.

Comment: I don't know what is causing the REPL to hang there (I'm assuming you're using RStudio, I do not use it). I do notice that you have one more close-brace `}` than you have open-brace, that could either be an indication of an incomplete copy/paste into this question or something else going on with your code. I generally put the left-brace on the same line as `while` (and `for` and `if` and `function` and ...), and while that is heavily *style*, perhaps something else is going on ...

Comment: @csgroen @r2evans I added a break after the try-error `if(!is(zip, 'try-error')) break` and deleted the extra } at the end. It seems to be downloading the second file listed regardless of circumstance presented and I get a "Error: unexpected '}' in "}"" message after download completes. Well...it's some progress, anyway.

Comment: Still not sure you need the while loop here. Can you make a vector of all the websites you want to scrape (`websites`) and loop over that with `for(website_dir in websites)`?

Comment: @csgroen I would do that, but I need to end up with just a single file. It's part of a larger automated process - I have some scripts later that grab the extracted file and use it and I want to ensure it is the most recent file/avoid download errors if the website doesn't update when I expect.

Comment: So wait, you want it to keep trying previous months until it gets the most recent data? Is that the idea?

Comment: @csgroen Essentially, though I shouldn't have to go back more than one month. Though, now that I think about it, I could just put the most recent month at the end of the list `list(January, February, March)` and have the zip file object rewrite with each download. If there's a download error for ex - March, then I'll still have the next most recent month ex - February that was downloaded and written to that object previously.

Comment: Now the while loop makes a little more sense. I'll update my answer, brb.

Comment: Answer updated. Try that ;)

Comment: @csgroen Thanks for bearing with me through the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code to test last month and keep going until you find the most recent file:

```
require(tidyverse)
# Set dates
today <- Sys.Date() # today

# Set directory
data_dir <- '/tmp/'
website_dir <- 'https://edcintl.cr.usgs.gov/downloads/sciweb1/shared/uswem/web/conus/eta/modis_eta/monthly/downloads/m'

i <- 1
while(TRUE) {
    last_test_month <-  format(today - months(i), "%Y%m")
    zip <- download.file(paste0(website_dir, last_test_month, '.zip'), destfile=paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), mode='wb')
    i = i + 1
    if(!is(zip, 'try-error')) break
}
unzip(paste0(data_dir, 'test.zip'), exdir=data_dir)
```